# Как распечатать массив элементов List<T>? C# консольное приложение

Tags: c#, массивы, list, консоль, вывод

Интересует есть ли какой алгоритм распечатки всех элементов листов, которые(листы) расположены в одномерном массиве. Пример:

```
private List<int>[] list  = new List<int>[20]; //списочная структура
```

У меня эта структура используется в графе(если что).

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "распечатать"? Вывести в консоль?

Comment: да, вывести каждое значение каждого листа

Comment: Если что у вас массив  списков проинициализирован, но сами списки в этом массиве не проинициализированы

Comment: они инициализируются при добавлении вершины

Comment: Ну тогда все хорошо, метод для вывода в ответе

Comment: премного благодарна)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void WriteLineItems(List<int>[] lists)
{
    foreach(var list in lists)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }   
}
```